# Не могу запустить sidekiq

Tags: linux, ruby

Добрый день. Подскажите с такой проблемкой. Есть 2 сервака. С настроенным окружением. Хочу в `GOD.rb` добавить `sidekiq`, на одном сервере сделал это без проблем, а на втором не хочет и я не пойму почему.

Что имеем:

```
god status
god status
sidekiq: unmonitored
unicorn: up
unicorn_rails: up
```

Когда делаю `god start sidekiq`

вижу sidekiq: up
Но в процессах его не вижу. В логах

```
INFO: sidekiq moved 'up' to 'up'
INFO: sidekiq [trigger] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
INFO: sidekiq move 'up' to 'start'
INFO: sidekiq before_start: no pid file to delete (CleanPidFile)
INFO: sidekiq start: cd /var/www/myproject/current && rvm use ruby-2.2.2 do bundle exec sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile /var/www/myproject/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid --environment production --logfile /var/www/myproject/shared/log/sidekiq.log --daemon
W [2015-11-16 16:56:38]  WARN: sidekiq start command exited with non-zero code = 127
```

Повторюсь что на другом сервере я его запустил за 1 мин.

Comment: среди параметров программы *rvm* присутствует имя лог-файла. в него что-то попадает при попытке запуска?

Comment: Нет он пустой, но видно что дата изменения файла меняется.

Comment: попробуйте выполнить команду вручную без демонизации и посмотреть, будет ли какой-нибудь вывод

Comment: команда выполняется успешно.

Comment: 1. и процесс запускается и присутствует в списке процессов? 2. *успешно* — а код возврата ноль или 127? посмотреть код возврата последней выполненной команды: `echo $?`.

Comment: Там была проблема с env. Забыл отписать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что в папке куда должен был писать pid файл не было прав.